# appointment plugin doesn't display all appointments

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to create a appointment plugin, and so far it is working that I can create appointments and see the detail view from the appointment.

The problem is, on a page called "appointments" where I wan't to list all appointments, nothing is displayed. I also would like to know, how I can modify the way all appointments are styled. I would like to have it placed in 4 columns.

I know the markup for this columns, but I don't know where I have to modify the plugin.

Here are the 5 files from my plugin:

termine.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Termine
 * Description: Terminverwaltung für Wordpress
 * Author: Me
 * Version: 1.0
 */

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
    require_once('posttype.php');
    require_once('datumsbox.php');
    require_once('termineansicht.php');
    require_once('seite.php');

?>
```

posttype.php

```
<?php 

    add_action('init','post_type_termine');

    function post_type_termine(){

        register_post_type(
            'termine', 

            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'Termine',
                    'singular_name' => 'Termin',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Neuen Termin anlegen'
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,

                'supports' => array(
                    'title','excerpt','editor','thumbnail','custom-fields'
                )
            )

        );

    }

?>
```

datumsbox.php (used to place a box with appointment-details in the backend)

```
<?php

    add_action('add_meta_boxes','nw_termine_addmetaboxes');

    add_action('save_post','nw_termine_savedata');

    function nw_termine_addmetaboxes(){

        add_meta_box(
            'termine_metabox',
            'Datum und Ort',
            'termine_datumsbox',
            'termine',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );

    }

    function termine_datumsbox(){

        wp_nonce_field('termine_action', 'termine_name');


        echo '<label for="myplugin_field1">Tag: </label>'; 
        $wert1=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_tag',true);
        echo '<input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="31" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_field1" value="'.$wert1.'" style="width:4em"/>';

        echo '<label for="myplugin_field2">Mon.: </label>'; 
        $wert2=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_monat',true);
        echo '<input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="12" id="myplugin_new_field2" name="myplugin_field2" value="'.$wert2.'" style="width:4em" />';  

        echo '<label for="myplugin_field3">Jahr: </label>'; 
        $wert3=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_jahr',true);
        echo '<input type="number" step="1" min="2011" max="2020" id="myplugin_new_field3" name="myplugin_field3" value="'.$wert3.'" style="width:5em"/>';

        echo '<br/><label for="myplugin_field4">Stunde: </label>';
        $wert4=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stunde',true);
        echo '<input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="23" id="myplugin_new_field4" name="myplugin_field4" value="'.$wert4.'" style="width:4em"/>';  

        echo '<label for="myplugin_field5">Min.: </label>';
        $wert5=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_minute',true);
        echo '<input type="number" step="1" min="00" max="59" id="myplugin_new_field5" name="myplugin_field5" value="'.$wert5.'" style="width:4em"/>';  

        echo '<br/><label for="myplugin_field7">Bis: </label>';
        $wert7=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_bis',true);
        echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field7" name="myplugin_field7" value="'.$wert7.'" /> (beliebiger Text)';   

        echo '<br/><br/><label for="myplugin_field6">Adresse für Google Maps: </label><br/>'; 
        $wert6=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_geo',true);
        echo '<input  id="myplugin_new_field6" name="myplugin_field6" value="'.$wert6.'" style="width:90%" />';   

        echo '<br/><br/><label for="myplugin_field8">Angezeigte Adresse: </label><br/>'; 
        $wert8=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_geoanzeige',true);
        echo '<input  id="myplugin_new_field8" name="myplugin_field8" value="'.$wert8.'" style="width:90%" />';   

    }


    function nw_termine_savedata($post_id){

        if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
        if( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) return false;
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['termine_name'],'termine_action') ) return false;


        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_tag', $_POST['myplugin_field1'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_monat', $_POST['myplugin_field2'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_jahr', $_POST['myplugin_field3'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_stunde', $_POST['myplugin_field4'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_minute', $_POST['myplugin_field5'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_geo', $_POST['myplugin_field6'], false); 
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_bis', $_POST['myplugin_field7'], false);
        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_geoanzeige', $_POST['myplugin_field8'], false);

        $zeitstempel=mktime((int) $_POST['myplugin_field4'],(int) $_POST['myplugin_field5'],0,(int) $_POST['myplugin_field2'],(int) $_POST['myplugin_field1'],(int) $_POST['myplugin_field3']);

        update_post_meta($_POST['post_ID'], '_zeitstempel', $zeitstempel, false);

    }
?>
```

termineansicht.php (detailview of an appointment)

```
<?php

    add_action('the_content','nw_termine_ansicht');

    function nw_termine_ansicht( $content ){

        if ( get_post_type() != 'termine') return $content;

        $custom = get_post_custom (get_the_ID());

        $datumsformat = "%A, den %e. %B %G";

        $zeitanzeige = strftime($datumsformat,$custom['_zeitstempel'][0]);

        if(strftime('%R',$custom['_zeitstempel'][0])!='00:00'){
            $zeitanzeige.=strftime(', um %H:%M Uhr',$custom['_zeitstempel'][0]);
        }

        if(isset($custom['_bis'][0]) AND $custom['_bis'][0]!=''){
            $zeitanzeige .= ' bis '.$custom['_bis'][0];
        }

        $datum='<div class="zeitanzeige" style="'.$options['style'].'">'.$zeitanzeige.'</div>';

        $ort='';

        if(isset($custom['_geo']) AND $custom['_geo'][0]!=''){
            $geo=urlencode($custom['_geo'][0]);

            if(isset($custom['_geoanzeige'][0]) AND $custom['_geoanzeige'][0]!='') $adresse=$custom['_geoanzeige'][0];
            else $adresse=$custom['_geo'][0];

            $ort='<div class="googlemaps"><strong>Ort:</strong> '.$adresse;
            $ort.='<a href="https://maps.google.de/maps?q='.$geo.'" class="aufmapsanzeigen"><img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='.$geo.'&zoom=14&size=600x180&sensor=false&markers=color:green|'.$geo.'"/></a>';
            $ort.='<a href="https://maps.google.de/maps?q='.$geo.'" class="aufmapsanzeigen">Auf Google Maps anzeigen »</a>';
            $ort.='</div>';
        }

        return $datum . $content . $ort;

    }

?>
```

termine.php (a list of all appointments)

```
<?php

class terminadd{

    function rewrite_post($mypost){

        $mypost = stripslashes($mypost);

        if(preg_match("/\[termine\]/",$mypost)){

            $termininfo = "Termin";

            // Hole alle Termine    
            // die vergangen sind oder noch kommen  
            if(isset($_GET['archiv'])){
                $order='DESC'; $compare='<';
                $title="Vergangene Termine";
            }else{
                $order='ASC'; $compare='>=';
                $title="Kommende Termine";
            }

            $posts = get_posts(
                array('post_type'=>'termine',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key' => '_zeitstempel',
                        'order' => $order,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => '_zeitstempel',
                                    'value' => time(),
                                    'compare' => $compare
                                )
                        )
                    )
            ); 


            $termininfo = "$title ";    

            ob_start();
            global $post;

            foreach ($posts AS $post){
                setup_postdata($post);
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            }

            $mypost = preg_replace("/\[termine\]/",ob_get_contents(),$mypost);
            ob_end_clean();

        }

        return $mypost;
    }

}

add_action('the_content', array(new terminadd(), 'rewrite_post'));
```

I've uploaded these files here:

[appointment plugin download](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9030398/termine.zip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, replacing content, especially with output buffering, is, at least in my mind, not very good practice. So you might consider making use of wordpress' templating system - see [Codex: Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) for a start.

The former would also lead to, where your markup has to go. Or if you not using templates you have to write it into above files. Actually you are making use of templates already, with:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

Which is looking for `content-the-post-format.php`, but shouldn't this be:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
```

So you can create a template file `content-the-post-type.php` for that.

Additionally you are using `$posts` as variable name which is a [global variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) name used by wp, so this will lead to problems. Change the variable to a none-used/reserved name, generally, try using distinct and unique names to avoid conflicts. There is not need for the `global $post;` you are doing, you should also add `wp_reset_postdata()` to your code. Best you take another read of - at least - [Codex: get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to learn more yourself about how to do this.

These are just some pointers of course, but they should get you going into the right direction.